# How to get the response time of a json web service request?

Tags: java, json, rest

I make a post request to a web service as below and I need to get the response time of each web service.

```
given().headers("Content-Type", "application/json", "----", "----")
                    .body(body).when().post(BaseUrl)
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the time in nanoseconds, wrap this around your request:

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
// ... the code being measured ...
long responseTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
```

Remember that this will also capture any processing time, so will be longer than the actual network response time. But it should be useful for the sake of comparison between different requests.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful. My issue is I need to get the exact response time of the web service. Any other ideas?